# DAR archive GUI utilities for Mac/Windows?

Tags: gui, archiving

Are there any DAR archive utilities that work for Mac / Windows?

All I can find are the command line programs, and the GUI programs for Linux.

Comment: if GTK+ is available thru MacPorts you might coax this one into compiling: http://dargui.sourceforge.net/

Comment: the CLI for DAR is fine, it's not that hard.  Try something like:  `dar -c /home/thufir/Desktop/thufir2012march03 -s 880M -p -b -z -R /home/thufir2 -D`  although i guess this is an older question.   http://blog.gmane.org/gmane.comp.sysutils.backup.dar.support for support.

Answer (score 2):

The [wikipedia article](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/DAR_(Disk_Archiver)) only mention [DarGUI](http://dargui.sourceforge.net/) and [KDar](http://kdar.sourceforge.net/) as available GUI frontends, and searching reveals nothing else. Of those my guess is that DarGUI is the simplest to get to work on windows or mac.

http://kdar.codeplex.com/releases/view/40326

Comment: Weird that 7zip can't do it......

Comment: @Pacerier  I don't think 7zip has nearly the capabilities of DAR.  DAR will take a directory (or the entire drive), and create a series of slices, let's say each slice is 880MB, and then just put 5 slices per DVD.  That way the DVD is full.  Or, just store the slices on another hard drive.  Or tape...    see also http://askubuntu.com/questions/187954/optimum-slice-size-for-backing-up-data-to-dvd  DAR uses tar to make the slices; compression is optimal but suggested.  In a way, DAR is just a nice way of making a series of tar balls (slices) of a specified size.

Comment: @Thufir, How is this different from the ["split to volumes"](http://i.stack.imgur.com/qk2d3.png) feature in 7z?

Comment: @Pacerier DAR creates `slice1.dar`, then `slice2.dar`..`slice<n>`.  Each slice of specified size; that might be the same.  It also does incremental backups, like time machine, etc.